# Как сохранить часть окна в изображение?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, render, primaryscreen

Пишу проект для генерации карт. Одна из требуемых возможностей - сохранение и печать полученного изображения.

[image: Вот пример карты:]

---

Я пыталась сделать скриншот:

```
screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()

screen.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId(), 0, 0, 100, 100)
```

но функция сохранения данного объекта не работает:

```
screen.save(filename, 'jpg')
```

---

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить эту карту и выводить на печать полученное изображение?

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, `QApplication.primaryScreen()` - работает:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        pix = QtGui.QPixmap('D:/_Qt/img/cat.jpg')
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()                              
        self.label.setPixmap(pix.scaled(100, 100, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.num = 1

        grab_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Сделать Screen картинки')
        grab_btn.clicked.connect(self.click_handler)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(grab_btn)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


    def click_handler(self):

        screen     = QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen()
        screenshot = screen.grabWindow( self.label.winId() )    
        screenshot.save('shot{}.jpg'.format(self.num), 'jpg')

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('shot{}.jpg'.format(self.num))
        label_pixmap = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label_pixmap.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.layout.addWidget(label_pixmap)

        self.num += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если вы рисуете ее на `QWidget`, или его наследнике, то у него есть такой метод как `render()` при помощи которого вы можете отобразить ваш план в `QPixmap` и сохранить уже его. Пример (допустим мы находимся в слоте сохранения карты):

```
//...
QPixmap pixmap(self.widget.size())
self.widget.render(pixmap);
pixmap.save("filename.jpg");
//...
```

Кроме того, у метода `QWidget.render()` имеются дополнительные параметры, при помощи которых вы можете уточнить какую именно часть карты/плана вам необходимо сохранять